# Dynamic relation between enteties in Symfony2

Tags: entity, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am new to Symfony2 and stuck at the following problem.

I have an entity called "Queue", that represents a playlist. This playlist-items can be songs or moderation. The queue has two fields, "itemType" and "itemId".

What i need to do is to connect a queue item with the correct item from the songs entity (if itemType is 'song') or to the correct item from the moderation entity (if itemType is 'moderation') where itemId is the primary key of the specific database.
This way i could use artisttrackname, etc in the template.

In the future there will be a need to add more itemTypes, so adding seperate id-fields is not an option.

thanks.

Comment: What do you need from such dynamic connections? If you want to just save/retrieve entities dynamically, you can use DQL's to retrieve datasets by joining entity tables manually. Or, you can use custom hydration (described in Native SQL chapter of manual)

Comment: You are right, thats exactly what I needed. I was thinking way to complicated... Would you put your text into an answer, so i can close the question? Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Posted as an answer with some manual link. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you need from such dynamic connections? If you want to just save/retrieve entities dynamically, you can use [DQL's](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) to retrieve datasets by joining entity tables manually. Or, you can use custom hydration (described in [Native SQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html) chapter of manual)